# On which system does sqlite is not included

Tags: sqlite

I currently need to manage translations for one of my applications (C++). Basically I am still in mid of the decision wether to use sqlite or csv. I am currently tending towards sqlite, because I don't need to write my own code for parsing (and the code is already well tested) and it's faster. The database design is pretty easy (basically just one entity with 3 weak entities for 3 textxs in different languages). The only thing I was not quite sure about with sqlite is that it might need an additional installation which makes the deployment more complicated (using linux and windows). I only found that sqlite is already installed on most LinuxOS, but nothing on Windows, so is it already included there (is a install even needed when I use the c library provided by them)? Do you see any other advantages in using csv files except that they are directly readable and no installation is required?

Comment: The simplest way to use SQLite from C++ is to compile the SQLite source amalgamation (`sqlite3.c`) into your application.

Comment: ah ok I already did that, which worked fine. Just wanted to be sure thats really all I need to do (how can I mark the question as solved?)

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't really do "solved" or "unsolved" like discussion forums. I'll post an answer, and you can accept it or not, as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to use SQLite from a C++ (or a C) application is to compile the `sqlite3.c` amalgamated source file into your application. Just add it to your source tree, and include `sqlite3.h`.

Comment: Useful reading: https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html (especially the platform configuration section; I have autoconf or cmake tests for all those and make sure to compile with `-D_HAVE_SQLITE_CONFIG_H` so that `config.h` is included)

Comment: Is it worth the effort building the almagation file myself? (and when building a static library from the standard almagation file is it compatible both with linux and windows?)

Comment: Not unless you need the database engine to an external library for some reason. And you would have to build an `.a` static library for Linux, and a `.lib` file for Windows.

Comment: from my reading .a and .lib are the same (well with a different name) is that right?

Comment: They serve the same purpose, but they are not compatible.

Comment: can I create a .lib on linux?

Comment: No, gcc will produce an `.so` shared library, or an `.a` static library for Linux. It can't produce a `.lib` or a `.dll` for Windows.

Comment: @maxbachmann If you're just including sqlite.c directly in your project's source files there's no reason to compile a library version.

Comment: Just tested and realised that there is really not enough difference in compile time to make it worth building the library